# Integrate $\int \frac{x\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx$

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

> $$\int \frac{x\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx$$

$$\int \frac{x\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx=\int \frac{x\cos x}{1-\cos^2x}dx=\int \frac{x\cos x}{(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}dx$$

How can I find the two fractions? if there are at all?

Comment: You are missing a $dx$

Comment: @gbox you can find the fractions by expressing $\cos x$ as $(1+\cos x)-(1-\cos x)$

Comment: @AdityaDev can you elaborate more? I did not understand

Comment: @gbox try expanding (1+cosx)-(1-cosx)

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}=\csc x \cot x$$
Applying integration by parts and differentiating 'x' we get,

$$I= \int \frac{x\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx=-x \csc x +\int \csc x\,dx$$

Now can you proceed?

Answer (score 3):

For the calculation of $$I=\int \csc(x)\,dx$$ the tangent half angle subsitution is very useful and makes everything simple $$t=\tan(\frac x2)\implies dx=\frac {2dt}{1+t^2}\qquad \csc(x)=\frac{1+t^2}{2t}$$ All of this makes $$I=\int \frac{dt} t$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice, using integration by parts $$\int \frac{x\cos x}{\sin^2 x}\ dx$$
$$=x\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}\ dx-\int \left(\frac{d}{dx}(x)\cdot \int  \frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}\ dx\right)\ dx$$
$$=x\int \frac{d(\sin x)}{\sin^2 x}-\int \left(1\cdot \int  \frac{d(\sin x)}{\sin^2 x}\ dx\right)\ dx$$
$$=x\cdot \frac{-1}{\sin x}-\int \left(\frac{-1}{\sin x}\right)\ dx$$
$$=-x\csc x +\int \csc x\ dx$$
$$=-x\csc x +\ln|\csc x-\cot x|+C$$

Comment: Very nice approach. +1

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{x\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx$$
Let $\sin x=u$. Then, $\cos x dx=du$ and $x=\arcsin u$.
$$\int \frac{x\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx=\int \frac{\arcsin u}{u^2}du$$
This can be integrated by parts taking $\arcsin u$ as the first function and $\frac{1}{u^2}$ as the second function.

Comment: it lead me to $\frac{arcsinx}{x}-\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Comment: $$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\text{d}x=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{1-x^2}=u\\-\frac{x}{ \sqrt{1-x^2}}\text{d}x=\text{d}u\end{bmatrix}=-\int\frac{1}{x^2}\text{d}u=\int \frac{1}{u^2-1}\text{d}u$$ and we can use partial fraction. It is not so easy, but possible to use this way.

Comment: @gbox Now, you can say let $k=x^2$. Then, you get $\int \frac{dk}{2k\sqrt{1-k}}$. Then, let $1-k=v^2$. That results in $-\int \frac{dv}{1-v^2}$, which can be easily evaluated.

Comment: @Galc127 There should be no $u$ in the denominator I think.

Comment: @GoodDeeds, you are correct, I will edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{x\cos x}{(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}dx=\int\frac{x \cos x}{1-\cos^2 x}dx=\int x\cot x \csc xdx$$ 
And now by parts: $f=x$ and $df=dx$ and $dg=\cot x \csc x dx$ and $g=-\csc$

$$=-x \csc x+\int\csc x dx$$

Multiply numenator and denominator of $\csc x$ by $\cot x +\csc x$

$$-x\csc x-\int\frac{-\cot x \csc x-\csc^2 x}{\cot x+\csc x}dx$$

And now set $t=\cot x +\csc x$ and $dt=(-\csc^2 x-\cot x \csc x)dx$

$$=-x\csc x-\int \frac 1 t dt$$ Can you finish?

Comment: Why do I need to "Multiply numenator and denominator of $\csc x$ by $\cot x +\csc x$"

Answer (score 2):

Since you wanted to solve using partial fractions,
$$\int\frac{x\cos x}{(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{x(1+\cos x)-x(1-\cos x)}{(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{x}{1-\cos x}dx- \frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{x}{1+\cos x}}dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x}{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}dx- \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x}{2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int x\sec^2\frac{x}{2}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int x\csc^2\frac{x}{2}dx$$
Now use integration by parts.
I will solve one term
$$\int x\sec^2\frac{x}{2}dx=2x\tan\frac{x}{2}-2\int\tan\frac{x}{2}dx$$

Comment: how did you get to $$\int\frac{x\cos x}{(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)}=\int\frac{x(1+\cos x)-x(1-\cos x)}{(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)}$$?

Comment: @gbox I missed a 1/2 term. See the edited answer.

Comment: It's a useful method. I did that to split the integral into two fractions. I posted this answer to help you with your method.

Answer (score 1):

You should recognize the derivative of the cosecant. Then by parts,

$$\int \frac{x\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx=-\frac x{\sin(x)}+\int\frac{dx}{\sin(x)}.$$

The last integral is easily solved with

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sin(x)}=\int\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin^2(x)}dx=\int\frac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)}dx=-\text{artanh}(\cos(x)).$$